# Calculating AUC for multiclass classification without sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, auc

I am trying to write a code that calculates AUC for multiclass classification without sklearn.

We are given a list of lists where left one is class and right one - is its score from model.

My prototype below (based on OvO method) works well as far as there are only two classes (as in examples 1 to 4). Starting from example 5, it returns AUC that differs from the expected (i.e. example 5 should provide AUC 0.538462, while mine returns 0.5083333333333333.)

```
import itertools

# example 1

# class_score = [
# [0,0],
# [1,1]
# ]

# example 2

# class_score = [
# [0,1],
# [1,0]
# ]

# example 3

# class_score = [
# [0.5, 0],
# [0.5, 1],
# [2, 0.5]
# ]

# example 4

# class_score = [
# [0,0],
# [0,1],
# [1,2],
# [0,3],
# [1,4],
# [1,5],
# [1,6]
# ]


# example 5

# class_score = [
# [0,4],
# [3,0],
# [1,2],
# [2,4],
# [1,0],
# [2,1],
# [4,1],
# [2,1],
# [4,4],
# [0,0]
# ]

# example 6

class_score = [
[3,4],
[3,4],
[2,1],
[3,2],
[4,1],
[0,2],
[2,0],
[1,2],
[4,4],
[3,3]
]

unique_classes = set(i[0] for i in class_score)

# classes_combinations

auc = 0
counter = 0

for cl0, cl1 in itertools.combinations(unique_classes, 2):
  battlefield = [i for i in class_score if i[0] in (cl0, cl1)]
  class_1 = [i for i in battlefield if i[0] == cl1]
  class_0 = [i for i in battlefield if i[0] == cl0]
  upper = 0
  for pair1 in class_1:
    for pair2 in class_0:
      if pair1[1] > pair2[1]:
        upper += 1
      if pair1[1] == pair2[1]:
        upper += 0.5
  auc +=  upper/((len(class_1) * len(class_0)))
  counter += 1


auc / counter
```

Comment: just to confirm,  the code gets `unique_classes={0, 1, 2, 3, 4}` in the above... and the return value is `0.55`.

Comment: Yes (for example 6), and the expected AUC is 0.648649

Comment: i agreee with your return for example 5 (`0.508333`), but how do you know that AUC = 0.538462 and why would you expect the same ?

Comment: I am solving a published problem where class-score examples and their expected AUCs are provided

Comment: understood,  please add a link to the same published problem.

Comment: Sure, it'a problem to solve in order to participate in on-site Yandex intern day: https://yandex.ru/yaintern/intern-day?from=contest_new . You got the problem via email after you register

Comment: I don't understand how you're supposed to compute a OvO AUC when you're only given the score for the correct class.

Comment: I used this article as a reference (https://dasha.ai/en-us/blog/auc-roc). In my understanding, with AUC equals 1 any two classes should be clearly separated by its scores (i.e. class i has scores 1-3, while class j - scores 4-6).

Comment: "score" must mean something other than confidence then?

Comment: Yes, 'score' means not confidence or probability